# Testcontainers questions when working with the driver

Tags: testcontainers

Good day!

I am just starting to use testcontainers. In this regard, a number of questions arose.
error when launching in chrome

```
10:27:50.632 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@2a0e7630, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=chrome, webdriver.chrome.driver=[--ignore-ssl-errors=true], goog:chromeOptions={useAutomationExtension=true, args=[--ignore-certificate-errors, --no-sandbox], extensions=[]}, takesScreenshot=true, acceptInsecureCerts=true}]])
10:27:50.644 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@2a0e7630, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=chrome, webdriver.chrome.driver=[--ignore-ssl-errors=true], goog:chromeOptions={useAutomationExtension=true, args=[--ignore-certificate-errors, --no-sandbox], extensions=[]}, takesScreenshot=true, acceptInsecureCerts=true}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf) on port 14181
Only local connections are allowed.
[0.081][WARNING]: PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation

      org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:334)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:315)
    at ru.sbtqa.ufs.ui.stepdefinitions.BeforeTestUI.beforeclass(BeforeTestUI.java:57)
    at ru.sbtqa.ufs.ui.stepdefinitions.BeforeTestUI.setUp(BeforeTestUI.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:26)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:20)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
    at cucumber.runner.HookDefinitionMatch.runStep(HookDefinitionMatch.java:16)
    at cucumber.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:65)
    at cucumber.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:50)
    at cucumber.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:42)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:50)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:146)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:68)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:23)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:73)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:126)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber$RunCucumber.evaluate(Cucumber.java:156)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:88)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:327)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:523)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:329)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

Standard code

BrowserWebDriverContainer<?> container = new BrowserWebDriverContainer<>()
.withCapabilities(new FirefoxOptions())
.withRecordingMode(VncRecordingMode.RECORD_ALL, new File("target"), VncRecordingFormat.MP4)     .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(10)).withNetwork(Network.newNetwork());

1. Can only chrome and FireFox browsers be used?
   yandex and egde not available?

Comment: Whoa boy, I am going through something similar right now.  Are you executing the test within the container?  You need the browser (Chrome and Firefox installs for me, edge fails), java jre, and of course the web drivers for your browser (chrome or chrome headless).  Also make sure there isn't authentication in the way.

Comment: Please try to split up your questions into multiple single questions and add a code example for your second question.

Comment: I'm not running in a container ```public static target BrowserWebDriverContainer <?> container = new BrowserWebDriverContainer <> () .withCapabilities (en.sbtqa.tag.pagefactory.drivers.Capabilities.getFirefoxOptions ())
.withRecordingMode (VncRecordingMode.RECORD_ALL, new file ("target"), VncRecordingFormat.MP4) .withStartupTimeout (Duration.ofMinutes (2)). withNetwork (Network.newNetwork ());
container.start();```   Only works in firefox. An error occurs in chrome

Comment: through the driver, everything works for me in any browser. I would like to and through testcontainers